# Spacing or Horizontal lines in custom VS Code grammar

Tags: visual-studio-code, grammar, vscode-extensions

I just worked into grammar creation with Atom and now VS Code and I'm currently developing an own grammar in VS Code.
In the text file I cannot insert extra spacings, but I would like to separate logical blocks with an Bigger spacing or an horizontal line. 
But I don't now how to achieve this, because as far as I figured out none of the VS Code templates scopes allows such a style.

Could someone tell me how I can achieve this?
As far as I figured out I will need to add a custom scope to each used template?

[image: Current structur]

[image: With horizontal line]

[image: With spacing]

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible. Visual Studio Code is not a text processor, but a source code editor. If you want separation simply add an empty line.